# Was HP's IMAGE database available on the 2100/2000 line?

Tags: hp, database

I'm reading about the history of the HP 21xx series in [this interview](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/chac/CHAC_Analytical_Engine/2.4_August_1995.pdf), and one thing has me confused. I never used these machines, so I can't be sure I have the context correct...

On page 5 he's talking about the Image database and how it ran on HP DOS but the other users wanted it to run on the R-T OS. This is in the middle of a section talking about the 21xx series, but I thought Image was only on the 3000?

Was it also on the 21xx, or is this whole section about Image basically an aside?

Comment: I hate to be snarky, but did you google IMAGE before asking this question?  Wikipedia has a pretty definite answer (though of course it might be wrong).

Comment: Do you mean the article [I helped write](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=IMAGE_(database)&action=history) and am actively collecting information on for a major update? It is that parenthetical part I am trying to check as I have found almost every claim of "first" or "only" to be quickly refuted here.

Comment: That would be the one.  It would have been helpful if you'd mentioned more research than this one interview.